WordPress salephpscripts web 2.0 web directory plugin - turn off notify moderator
The WP plugin salephpscripts Web 2.0 plugin shows a submission form on each listing page called 'Send Message to Moderator'. I want this whole feature to go away. It should not be displayed at all.
I've searched every settings page in the plugin's admin and find no mention of it. I've searched their documentation  and find no mention if it. I've even sic'ed ChatGPT on it and it was stumped as well.
Does anyone know where - or if - there is a setting to turn the 'Send Message to Moderator' form submission off?

https://www.salephpscripts.com/wordpress_directory/demo/documentation/pages/single-listing-page/ - remove the [webdirectory-listing-report] shortcode?
